# Describe the solution set of the system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Consider the linear system below:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
x_1&-&2x_2&+&&&x_4&=&1\\  
2x_1& -& 5x_2& -& 2x_3& +& k^2x_4 &= &-2\\
&&x_2&+&2x_3&-&x_4&=&4
\end{array}$$

For $k = \sqrt{3}$, describe the solution set of the system.

**Attempt at a solution**

I tried to take its RREF, this is the matrix I acquired.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 9 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

The values at the right-hand coloumn are the solutions, however I have no clue where to move on from here..

Comment: **Hint:** what system does your reduced row-echelon form represent?

Comment: @Roger Burt We must have posted at the same time. Didn't mean to get in your way.

Comment: @PaulSundheim It's all good.

Answer (score 1):

From your reduced matrix:
$x_1+4x_3-x_4=9\\
x_2+2x_3-x_4=4$
where  $x_4$ and $x_3$ are free.  You therefore get
$\\x_1=-4s+t+9\\
x_2=-2s+t+4$

Can you get the solution set from here?